# How to inject dependencies when controller set up as a regular function

Tags: angularjs

In one of the [many Angularjs style guides](https://github.com/mgechev/angularjs-style-guide), it suggests setting up a controller like this

```
function myCtrl(dependency1, dependency2){

}
module.controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);
```

I tried it by doing the following, in which I also use a $watch on the $scope. However, I get an error that $watch is not a function, so I'm assuming that I'm not injecting the scope properly.

This is the code in my `app/controllers/myctrl.js` file

```
function MyCtrl($scope, myStorage){
         var mystore = $scope.mystore = myStorage.get();
         $scope.$watch('mystore', function(){
                 //code ommitted
         } 
}
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);
```

Question, How do I inject `$scope` and other dependencies using this style?

Previously, I did it this way and everything worked fine.

```
 angular.module('myApp').controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'myStorage',
             function MyController($scope, myStorage){

             }
       ]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MyCtrl.$inject = ['dependency1', 'dependency2'];
function MyCtrl(dependency1, dependency2){

}
```

Yes, it can come *before* the function (just like an annotation in Java).